# Adding Google Maps API Keys to Python program

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I am trying to obtain Google Street View images of a route between Point A and Point B, and make them into a video.

I found [this](https://github.com/jblsmith/street-view-movie-maker) repository which does exactly what I want. The author mentions that:

> Lastly, and trickiest of all: the code requires API keys for Google Map's Street View and Directions APIs. Note: setting up the Street View API now requires a billing account! it tends to be free for small amounts of traffic, but you have to set it up anyway.

I managed to set up a Google Maps API key, and following instructions from Google's website [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/overview), I was able to make queries of the form

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=47.5763831,-122.4211769
&fov=80&heading=70&pitch=0&key=YOUR_API_KEY&signature=YOUR_SIGNATURE
```

and obtain the image that I want.

Now, in the Python code, there's a file [street_crawl.py](https://github.com/jblsmith/street-view-movie-maker/blob/master/street_crawl.py), where the following code is present:

```
import sys
from utils import *
from API_KEYS import API_KEY_DIRECTIONS, API_KEY_STREETVIEW

'''Google Street View Movie Maker
Usage is:
    python2 ./street_crawl.py lat1 lon1 lat2 lon2 output_filestem
For example, to make a one-second video of the entrance of Joshua Treet National Park:
    python2 ./street_crawl.py 33.669793 -115.802125 33.671796 -115.801851 joshua_tree
Note: usage requires your own API keys.
'''

def main(lat_lon_A, lat_lon_B, filestem, picsize):
    print "Tracing path from ({0}) to ({1})".format(lat_lon_A, lat_lon_B)
    # Request driving directions from A to B
    gd = googlemaps.Client(key=API_KEY_DIRECTIONS)
```

I tried running the code as it is given and it gave me an error that:

```
ImportError: No module named API_KEYS
```

My question here is - how do I enter my own API key here? Should I just replace the last line with:

```
gd = googlemaps.Client(key="MY API KEY HERE")
```

and comment out the call to `from API_KEYS import API_KEY_DIRECTIONS, API_KEY_STREETVIEW` ?

Or do I have to create a module(file?) called `API_KEYS` and add my keys in some specific format there?

I am new to Python, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the idea of the project is to have a `API_KEYS.py` where you will define `API_KEY_DIRECTIONS` and `API_KEY_STREETVIEW` (i.e. the keys for respective APIs). They should have documented it better.
Note that this file is included in [.gitignore of the project](https://github.com/jblsmith/street-view-movie-maker/blob/master/.gitignore).

Also, just FYI note that there are number of ways to deal with [hiding] API keys from the source code - they decided to use this one.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that it certainly can be the same key.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, I didn't use any of the 2 APIs, but they are certainly different. I don't know if the key value may be the same. In any case they need both names defined.

Comment: That's what I meant. The key can be the same for both APIs, ie. you don't need to generate different keys.